# Aws server is not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, devops

I have Nodejs code running on aws fargate container.
What I did just add one logic, tested code and pushed code to github. And AWS started pipeline process. When deployment failed I checked cloud watch to know why its failed.
So I found that my Nodejs code requrire one package to run @aws-sdk/middleware-endpoint.
When I tested my nodejs code in my local system I didn't received any such error.
Here is error I received in aws
[image]

After reading this error I installed package @aws-sdk/middleware-endpoint and my server is running well.
I am willing to know why @aws-sdk/middleware-endpoint is required suddenly. Although previously my all apis are working fine in same aws server, But today I saw requirement of @aws-sdk/middleware-endpoint.

Anyone can help me what is need of @aws-sdk/middleware-endpoint?

Comment: Have you tried posting at https://repost.aws/ ? I have found that I get some very good responses there for AWS related stuff.

Comment: Is this package registered at `package.json` file? Is it still working locally after deleting node_modules and then reinstalling it? If you used npm (not yarn), you maybe installed it but don't registered at the package file, and then, it is not installed running npm install. To reinstall and include as dependency into package.json file, you need to include the save flag: npm install --save